# Responsive CSS box/rectangle with top side arched and outlined

Tags: css

I need to create a footer with arched top side and it should have an outline too. I thought of using a image on the top and plain rectangle with the same bg color below it but I need it to be responsive on different devices. Is it possible with pure CSS without having to use different sized images? And cross-browser solutions please :)

I am not be able to post images here because I am new here, here you go: http://oi60.tinypic.com/vwf48.jpg

Comment: I personally would probably go with an SVG image in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer{
  height: 100px; width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 0 0;
}
```

```html
<footer></footer>
```

Here's a link to a Codepen.io example if you want to play around with it:

[**EXAMPLE LINK HERE**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JoNvYW)

Comment: Thanks  Alan. But it doesn't seem to be quite there. How can I have more control on the curved shape? And I might need to write some media queries for mobile devices.

Comment: @meerkat Play around with the % values. Is it too curved or not curved enough as it stands?

Comment: @meerkat No problem, if the answer was the one you wanted, could you approve and up-vote it?